# RESTKit and IPV6 for iOS

Tags: ios, rest, restkit, ipv6

Apple from this June is forcing all applications to work on an IPV6 only network. Apple also does all their testing for the applications review process on IPV6 only networks.

I am using RESTKit 0.24.0 to do the RESTFul interactions in my application and i wanted to know the following:

1.How do you check if an application will work on an IPV6 only network with a remote server? I have tried setting up a IPV-6 only network using internet sharing on my mac (https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2015/10/05/enabling-an-ipv6-only-network-using-internet-sharing-on-el-capitan/) and the application works fine. Is this enough proof that the app will work on an IPV6 only network with a remote web server?

2.Does RESTKit 0.24.0 support IPV6 networking. If not should i update RESTKit and are there any work arounds for using RESTKit with IPV6?

Also, i am from India where the adoption for IPV6 at this point is really poor.

Comment: Just use latest iOS base SDK, latest xcode. And your app has already supported IPV6. If apple reviewers rejected your app because blah blah blah.... IPV6. Just ask them double check and your app will pass. I tried it and success! Good luck

Comment: Yes i had a slight snag that our web servers werent working on IPV6. Once i fixed that the app review passed and got accepted! Thank you!

Comment: @user19342: Your servers don't need to support IPv6

Answer (score 0):

> How do you check if an application will work on an IPV6 only network with a remote server

Your solution seems fine; Apple [recommends a similar setup](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW16).

> Does RESTKit 0.24.0 support IPV6 networking.

RESTKit uses AFNetworking as its underlying network stack, so it should not be affected by the transport characteristics of the underlying network. It appears that AFNetworking supports IPv6 (although there is some forum chatter about the correctness of the reachability implementation, and no official documentation that I could find that explicitly asserts support).

Bottom line, as long as you are using host name, rather than address literals, to retrieve your REST resources, you "should" be fine--especially as your testing is working as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Our web servers weren't prepped to handle IPV6 once we fixed that the app got accepted. I did not have to change from RESTKit or upload a new binary! Thanks for the response.